# Connection refuse android to xampp http default

Tags: php, android, json, xampp

I want to send a request from Genymotion- Android api 21 to xampp with php 7 to get JSON response. The server side code is working properly but when the request sent to localhost the connection refuse. I using windows 8 so for the connection I used Microsoft Km-test loopback driver as a network adapter. when I type the ip address in the browser of Genymotion machine localhost appears properly and the specific page and JSON array appears.
this is the code :

```
HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(strings[0]);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

I have defined the Internet permission in Manifest.
Thanks.

Comment: in url what you are writing localhost or IP address ?

Comment: if you are writing like 'http://localhost/demo.php' then replace with like 'http://192.168.1.38/demo.php'

Comment: can you post your full code

Comment: @DhavalkumarSolanki I wrote this http://192.168.0.150/androidjsondata. and the code is in index.php